# Cayley graph of $A_5$ with generators $(1,2,3,4,5),(1,4,3,2,5)$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, finite-groups, geometric-group-theory, topological-graph-theory, cayley-graphs

The Cayley graph of $A_5$ with two generators of order 5 seems rather complicated. What is its graph genus (orientable or non-orientable)?

- The best I could get by trial and error is [an embedding without crossings on a sphere with 10 crosscaps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6KJ5.png).
- Running the following in Sage works in theory, but takes too long:

  `A5 = groups.permutation.Alternating(5)
  S = [(1,2,3,4,5),(1,4,3,2,5)]
  d = A5.cayley_graph(generators=S)
  bt = d.to_undirected()
  bt.genus()`
- In Sage we can also use JSMol to get a [not-so-helpful](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fO3lF.png) view of the graph.

Comment: The group $A_5$ has two connected non-isomorphic Cayley graphs with the mentioned properties, namely $\mathrm{Cay}(A_5,\{(1\ 2\ 3\ 4\ 5), (1\ 2\ 3\ 5\ 4)\})$ and $\mathrm{Cay}(A_5,\{(1\ 2\ 3\ 4\ 5), (1\ 2\ 4\ 5\ 3)\})$.

Comment: As we know, $A_5$ has two conjugacy classes of $5$-cycles. The two non-isomorphic Cayley graphs $\mathrm{Cay}(A_5,\{\pi,\tau\})$ arises from the fact that $\pi$ and $\tau$ belong to the same conjugacy class or not. One can check that the girth of $\mathrm{Cay}(A_5,\{\pi,\tau\})$ is $5$ if $\pi$ and $\tau$ belong to the same conjugacy class, and it is $4$ otherwise.

Comment: @M.FarrokhiD.G. Thanks very much. I suppose it's not clear whether those two have the same genus then.

Comment: The [question about Bring's sextic](https://mathoverflow.net/q/360089/41291) might hold the key...

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Really? The plot thickens...

Comment: The curve $\sum_{i=1}^5x_i=\sum_{i=1}^5x_i^2=\sum_{i=1}^5x_i^3=0$ has genus 4, and admits obvious action of $S_5$. So it "only" remains to find an $\mathbb R^3$ in $\mathbb C\mathrm P^4$ with large enough portion of the curve inside it (e.g. certainly real parts of $x_i$ are useless because of $\sum_{i=1}^5x_i^2=0$).

Answer (score 5):

I don't know exact genus. I suspect it is 4 but do not have a proof. So I am making this community wiki, maybe somebody can supply this information.

The generating cycles $p$ and $q$ satisfy $(pq)^3=(p^{-1}q)^2=1$, so the Cayley graph can be obtained as a quotient of a tiling of the hyperbolic plane in at least two ways. One may take either (click on images if you want to enlarge)

- the quotient of the [pentahexagonal tiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentahexagonal_tiling) [image]
  which makes succession of vertices along each line periodic with period 4, or
- the quotient of the [tetrapentagonal tiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrapentagonal_tiling) [image]
  which makes succession of vertices along each line periodic with period 6.

These give respectively the

- [icosidodecadodecahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icosidodecadodecahedron) [image], with Euler characteristic -16
  and
- [rhombidodecadodecahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhombidodecadodecahedron) [image] with Euler characteristic -6.

The first, if orientable, has genus 9 and if not, 18; the second, if orientable, has genus 4 and if not, 8.

As Bjørn Kjos-Hanssen explains in a comment below, the rhombidodecadodecahedron is actually orientable, so this gives **upper bound 4 on the orientable genus**.

Further info:

- Wikipedia pages link to [some Python code](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Tamfang/programs) but I never tried it myself
- Jeff Weeks' [Kaleidotile](http://geometrygames.org/KaleidoTile/index.html) can be used to generate the tilings above
- [Jonathan Bowers](http://www.polytope.net/hedrondude/trapez.htm) states that if the verf (the set of vertices adjacent to a fixed vertex) is a trapezoid then the polyhedron is orientable. In particular "raded" (rhombidodecadodecahedron) is orientable.

Here is one possible gluing scheme of the tetrapentagonal tiling giving a surface of genus 4: [image] After the gluing one gets three vertices 0, 1, 2, and ten edges - X,Y,Z,T,U oriented from 0 to 1 and a,b,c,d,e oriented from 0 to 2. Choosing 0 for basepoint, this gives ten loops $\alpha_0=ad^{-1}$, $\alpha_1=de^{-1}$, $\alpha_2=eb^{-1}$, $\alpha_3=bc^{-1}$, $\alpha_4=ca^{-1}$ and $\beta_0=XU^{-1}$, $\beta_1=UT^{-1}$, $\beta_2=TZ^{-1}$, $\beta_3=ZY^{-1}$, $\beta_4=YX^{-1}$ generating the fundamental group, with relations $\alpha_0\alpha_1\alpha_2\alpha_3\alpha_4=\beta_0\beta_1\beta_2\beta_3\beta_4=\alpha_0\beta_0\alpha_3\beta_2\alpha_1\beta_4\alpha_4\beta_1\alpha_2\beta_3=1$. Or, eliminating, say, $\alpha_0$ and $\beta_0$ from the first two relations, one is left with 8 generators and single relation $\alpha_3\beta_2\alpha_1\beta_4\alpha_4\beta_1\alpha_2\beta_3=\beta_1\beta_2\beta_3\beta_4\alpha_1\alpha_2\alpha_3\alpha_4$. So the first homology group is $\mathbb Z^8$, as it should be for a genus 4 surface.

One more gluing scheme on a genus 4 surface, constructed using the [regular map $\mathrm S4:\{5,5\}$](http://www.weddslist.com/rmdb/map.php?a=R4.6):

[image]

Comment: @BjørnKjos-Hanssen These two relations suffice (checked it with `GAP`). As for kaleidotile, the two pictures, with three colors each, are obtained with 3,5,5 and 2,5,5 respectively, sliding the point to the middle of the lower edge of the triangle.

Comment: @BjørnKjos-Hanssen Thanks for the bounty! Inspired by it, I found on Wikipedia the polyhedra corresponding to these quotient tesselations. I still do not know the exact genus, though.

Comment: @BjørnKjos-Hanssen Unfortunately I cannot figure out whether the rhombidodecadodecahedron is orientable. If it is this will give upper bound 4 on the oriented genus. If not, this will give upper bound 8 on the non-oriented genus.

Comment: @BjørnKjos-Hanssen Great! In his nomenclature it is "raded". So then the oriented genus is at most 4.

Comment: The rhombidodecadodecahedron has lots of crossings though, so I don't know how to actually get a genus 4 representation of it

Comment: @BjørnKjos-Hanssen Well in a sense it is itself such a representation. You mean a map on a sphere with 4 handles with no self-intersections?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean

Comment: @BjørnKjos-Hanssen Actually I tried to embed this last realization in 3d, but unfortunately it requires twisting all five holes around by 90° which mightily distorts the picture. Hope to figure out how to do it with minimal losses...

Comment: Thanks for still working on this! I hope to get back to it as well...

Comment: Thanks a lot for this wonderful answer! Can you suggest a nice reference for this? I have very much interested in this. How does the periodicity is implemented while maintaining the graph to be regular, for instance.

Comment: @Shamina Sorry, I don't have any good reference for that. I found some work about highly symmetric genus 4 surfaces but they essentially use imaginary numbers. Recently I also asked Henry Segerman on youtube https://youtu.be/p9iG1vmsxZQ but he thinks there is no nice embedding with more than dihedral symmetry.

Answer (score 2):

You can also get this graph with Ed Pegg's demo of Cayley Graphs at [Wolfram demonstrations](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/CayleyGraphs), by taking the bottom slider to permutation 94 of 120.[image]

Comment: This post, while useful in some ways (and not really convertible to a comment), has been flagged "not an answer". Maybe, as a compromise, make it CW?

Comment: @ToddTrimble it's a step in the right direction so I'd like to award the bounty... maybe undo the community wiki?

Comment: @BjørnKjos-Hanssen You'd be in the best position to judge which post best answers your question or helps you the most, so I defer to you.

Answer (score 2):

According to Sagemath documentation, the time complexity of their algorithm is
$$
\mathcal{O}\left(|V| \prod_{v \in V} (d(v) - 1)!\right).
$$
(Note that in this instance this evaluates to $6^{60}$.)

However, quick google search reveals that approach via integer linear programming or SAT solvers might be viable for this particular case. I suggest you contact the authors of the following articles:

[Stronger ILPs for the Graph Genus Problem](https://drops.dagstuhl.de/opus/volltexte/2019/11151/), 27th Annual European Symposium on Algorithms (ESA 2019)

[A Practical Method for the Minimum Genus of a Graph: Models and Experiments](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-319-38851-9_6),  International Symposium on Experimental Algorithms, SEA 2016: Experimental Algorithms, pp 75-88

Comment: Thanks that's neat!

Answer (score 1):

There are computer programs to try, although I don't know how fast they are (the problem at hand is NP-complete).

E.g. Sagemath has an implementation of genus computation:
http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/graphs/sage/graphs/genus.html

Comment: Have you tried it on your graphs?

Comment: I imagine it gets slow as the genus gets high, but for low genus it ought to be fast...

Comment: @BjørnKjos-Hanssen Also, documentation is horrible.

Comment: So I can check the genus for a 72-edge subset of the graph in a couple of minutes on Jupyter... but there are 120 edges in total

Comment: we always appreciate suggestions on how to improve Sagemath :-)

Comment: One thing that was confusing to me: what kinds of objects are the vertices of the Cayley graphs, in Sage? For instance `(12)(34)` gives a "not callable" error, and `PermutationGroupElement('(12)(34)')` isn't quite it either. I ended up doing a hack where I made a new group and forced them to be strings. @DimaPasechnik

Comment: it makes sense to specify which groups your permutations are coming from, i.e.
as follows:

`sage: p=PermutationGroupElement('(1,2)(3,4)',parent=A5)`

`sage: p in bt.vertices()`

`True`

Does this cover your needs?

Comment: @DimaPasechnik oh thanks I'll try that!